# Protractor: How should I propagate an error from within browser.executeAsync?

Tags: javascript, selenium, coffeescript, promise, protractor

If from a Protractor spec, I execute a script within browser.executeAsyncScript, how should I communicate that the script has indeed failed? Consider the following call to browser.executeAsyncScript:

```
browser.executeAsyncScript((callback) ->
  # How do I communicate an error condition here!?
  callback()
)
.then((data) ->
  console.log("Browser async finished without errors: #{data}")
, (data) ->
  console.log("Browser async finished with errors: #{data}")
)
```

What I want to happen is that the error callback to then is invoked. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [webdriverjs doc](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#467):

```
driver.executeAsyncScript(function() {
  var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/resource/data.json", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhr.send('');
}).then(function(str) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(str)['food']);
});
```

So, it does not seem to have an error callback, but you can pass some arguments to the callback method. You can use it to propagate errors.

Comment: Yeah, I've made it work by just passing a success/failure flag to the executeAsyncScript callback.

Comment: Documentation of the executeAsyncScript is now at https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html