# How can I ignore websocket (found in Network tab) in protractor?

Tags: angular, websocket, protractor

Basically Protractor hangs in our project, because there is this weird `xhr_streaming` activity in Network tab caused by some sort of websocket which never finishes. Is there a way in protractor or by using some additional node lib to ignore this request?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Protractor has no way of doing that, and it's a big loss in my opinion. The only way to make this work is to use:</strike>

```
beforeAll(() => {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
});
```

The problem is now that it won't wait for angular events anymore, and there could be times that elements are not visible yet.

Besides protractor, you could also have a look at Cypress.io. Personally I think it's much easier and more straight forward to write e2e with.

Maybe it works if you make the xhr request run outside the `NgZone`, and whenever it needs to do something, make it run back in the zone:

```
constructor(readonly nz: NgZone, readonly http: HttpClient) {}

startStreamingXhr(): void {
  this.nz.runOutsideAngular(() => this.http.get(...).subscribe((data) => {
    this.nz.run(() => {
      // do something with data
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately these are no good solutions for me as this is a client project and changing framework does not come into play. "browser.waitForAngularEnabled()" or "this.ignoreSynchronization = true" will not work as well, because this activity is spinning all the time in Network tab.

Comment: Regarding running xhr request outside NgZone. This change should be make on angular project side, correct?

Comment: @JacekGóraj correct, relatively easy and straightforward change

Comment: Could you give me any valuable URL that shows how to do it? I'm no expert on angular but I could give it to our frontend developers to analyze.

Comment: @JacekGóraj what angular version are you using?

Comment: Hey, we use angular 5

Comment: @JacekGóraj I've updated my answer with a pseudo example

Comment: hey, so I've convinced our frontend developer to do it. He had to open the websocket connection outside of angular zone as you suggested and it works! I think you can update your answer leaving only this one solution here. Cheers!

Comment: @JacekGóraj good to hear! I've updated my answer, to at least keep the suggestion of dropping protractor ;) because there are better solutions, in my opinion, out there

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use those options:

**Option 1**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21863295/6331748

**Option 2**

You can try to abort XHR in question. See the reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort

**Option 3**

[Protractor / Selenium XHR stays in status "pending"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944182/protractor-selenium-xhr-stays-in-status-pending)

Let me know if any of those options worked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried all of them and nothing seems to work. Seems like currently there is no way in protractor to solve this.